# Task<> does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-5.0, async-ctp

Client

```
iGame Channel = new ChannelFactory<iGame> ( new BasicHttpBinding ( BasicHttpSecurityMode . None ) , new EndpointAddress ( new Uri ( "http://localhost:58597/Game.svc" ) ) ) . CreateChannel ( );

public Task<SerializableDynamicObject> Client ( SerializableDynamicObject Packet )
{
    return Task<SerializableDynamicObject> . Factory . FromAsync ( Channel . BeginConnection , Channel . EndConnection , Packet , null );
}
```

Contract

```
    [OperationContract ( AsyncPattern = true )]
    IAsyncResult BeginConnection ( SerializableDynamicObject Message , AsyncCallback Callback , object State );

    SerializableDynamicObject EndConnection ( IAsyncResult Result );
```

Service

```
public IAsyncResult BeginConnection ( SerializableDynamicObject Message , AsyncCallback Callback , object State )
{
    dynamic Request = Message;
    dynamic Response = new SerializableDynamicObject ( );
    if ( Request . Operation = "test" )
    {
        Response . Status = true;
    }
    Response . Status = false;

    return new CompletedAsyncResult<SerializableDynamicObject> ( Response );
}

public SerializableDynamicObject EndConnection ( IAsyncResult Result )
{
    return ( Result as CompletedAsyncResult<SerializableDynamicObject> ) . Data;
}
```

Exposing Service from Silverlight Client

```
private async void myButton ( object sender , RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    dynamic Request = new SerializableDynamicObject ( );
    Request . Operation = "test";

    var task = Client ( Request );
    var result = await task;  // <------------------------------ Exception
}
```

Exception

```
Task<SerializableDynamicObject > does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'
```

**What**'s wrong ?

---

**Edit 1 :**

Briefly,

Visual studio 2012 RC **Silverlight 5 Application** consumes *Game* **WCF 4 Service** hosted in **ASP.net 4 Application** with ChannelFactory technique via Shared **Portable Library .NET4/SL5** contains the *iGame* interface with **Async CTP**

**Graph :**
ASP.NET **<=** Class Library ( Game ) **<=** Portable Library ( iGame ) **=>** Silverlight

---

**Edit 2 :**

- Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack.Silverlight5.dll is added in my SL5 Client
- using System . Threading . Tasks;

Comment: Please state the C# version and include the usings from the top of the file.

Comment: And if you're using the Async CTP, have you made sure to add a reference to the AsyncCtpLibrary.dll?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`GetAwaiter()`, that is used by `await`, is implemented as an extension method in the Async CTP. I'm not sure what exactly are you using (you mention both the Async CTP and VS 2012 RC in your question), but it's possible the Async targeting pack uses the same technique.

The problem then is that extension methods don't work with `dynamic`. What you can do is to explicitly specify that you're working with a `Task`, which means the extension method will work, and then switch back to `dynamic`:

```
private async void MyButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic request = new SerializableDynamicObject();
    request.Operation = "test";

    Task<SerializableDynamicObject> task = Client(request);
    dynamic result = await task;

    // use result here
}
```

Or, since the `Client()` method is actually not dynamic, you could call it with `SerializableDynamicObject`, not `dynamic`, and so limit using `dynamic` as much as possible:

```
private async void MyButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var request = new SerializableDynamicObject();
    dynamic dynamicRequest = request;
    dynamicRequest.Operation = "test";

    var task = Client(request);
    dynamic result = await task;

    // use result here
}
```

Answer (score 120):

I had this issue in one of my projects, where I found that I had set my project's .Net Framework version to 4.0 and async tasks are only supported in .Net Framework 4.5 onwards.

I simply changed my project settings to use .Net Framework 4.5 or above and it worked.

Comment: This was a case for me too. Changed from 4.0 to 4.5 and it worked.

Comment: Or install Microsoft.Bcl.Async nuget package to remain in 4.0

Answer (score 68):

Just experienced this in a method that executes a linq query.

```
public async Task<Foo> GetSomething()
{
    return await (from foo in Foos
                  select foo).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Needed to use `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` instead. N00b mistake.

Comment: For me it was ToListAsync() . Worked great.

Comment: Yes worked for me too - FirstOrDefaultAsync and adding a using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; - Core 2.2 Project

Answer (score 52):

You have to install [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) NuGet package to be able to use `async/await` constructs in pre-.NET 4.5 versions (such as Silverlight 4.0+)

Just for clarity - this package used to be called `Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack` and some old [tutorials](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/05/22/using-async-and-await-in-silverlight-5-and-net-4-in-visual-studio-11-with-the-async-targeting-pack) still refer to it.

Take a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2013/04/17/microsoft-bcl-async-is-now-stable/) for info from Immo Landwerth.

Comment: thank you for this - the server I am using is 4.0 and I am unable to do an upgrade to 4.5

Answer (score 4):

The Problem Occur Because the application I was using and the dll i added to my application both have different Versions.

Add this Package-
Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -Version 1.0.168

ADDING THIS PACKAGE async Code becomes Compatible in version 4.0 as well, because Async only work on applications whose Versions are more than or equal to 4.5

Answer (score 3):

You could still use framework 4.0 but you have to include `getawaiter` for the classes:

`MethodName(parameters).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: ConfigureAwait also does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your .NET version 4.5 or greater

Answer (score 2):

In my case just add `using System;` solve the issue.

Comment: Same, I am using UWP and it was just a missing using System; call.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I was calling a method

```
await myClass.myStaticMethod(myString);
```

but I was setting myString with

```
var myString = String.Format({some dynamic-type values})
```

which resulted in a `dynamic` type, not a `string`, thus when I tried to await on `myClass.myStaticMethod(myString)`, the compiler thought I meant to call `myClass.myStaticMethod(dynamic myString)`.  This compiled fine because, again, in a dynamic context, it's all good until it blows up at run-time, which is what happened because there is no implementation of the dynamic version of `myStaticMethod`, and this error message didn't help whatsoever, and the fact that Intellisense would take me to the correct definition didn't help either.
  Tricky!

However, by forcing the result type to string, like:

```
var myString = String.Format({some dynamic-type values})
```

to

```
string myString = String.Format({some dynamic-type values})
```

my call to `myStaticMethod` routed properly

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I had to remove the async keyword from the method and also remove the await keyword from the calling method to use getawaiter() without any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<model> GetSomething(int id)
{
    return await context.model.FindAsync(id);
}
```

Comment: please add a description to your code explaining op why your code should help him

Answer (score 0):

If it's using an interface, check that the interface returns a Task<> too

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) then ensure that you have a using statement for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, as such:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading;
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to reproduce this issue is:

```cs
await myvar = myFuncAsync();
```

Do this instead:

```cs
myvar = await myFuncAsync();
```