# Using function with return type Task<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I had a function that did the following:

```
public class UserClass
   {
   public static CurrentUserData GetUserInfo()
    {
        CurrentUserData ui;
            ui = GetUserData();
        return ui;
   }
   }
```

My CurrentUserData object is as follows:

```
   public class CurrentUserData 
   {
       public bool ReadOnly{get;set;}
  }
```

In my controller, I call my method and can see the ReadOnly property fine:

```
    var user = UserClass.GetUserInfo();
    if (user.ReadOnly)
 {
      ////code to execute
    }
```

I had to add an async call to my function, and now it looks likes this (I omitted code for brevity):

```
  public static Task<CurrentUserData > GetUserInfo()
    {
        Task<CurrentUserData > ui;
            ui = GetUserData();
          HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        return ui;
   }
```

Notice the Task I had to add. But when I call the method in my controller like before, I get the error:

```
 Error  CS1061  'Task<CurrentUserData >' does not contain a definition for 
 'ReadOnly' and no extension method 'ReadOnly' accepting a first argument of 
 type 'Task<CurrentUserData >' could be found (are you missing a using directive or 
 an assembly reference?)
```

What do I need to change so when any class calls my new Task method, it will see all the properties of the object wrapped in Task?

Comment: You need to go [async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You need to make all functions async all the way up to the controller.

Comment: You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853812/task-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-getawaiter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark your `GetUserInfo` method `async` and `await` the task you are returning to the other method:

```
public static async Task<UserClass> GetUserInfo()
{
     Task<UserClass> ui = GetUserData();
     HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
     return ui;
}

//and then
var user = await UserClass.GetUserInfo();
if (user.ReadOnly)
{
    // code to execute
}
```

That will make the task returned wait until it is done, and then you can continue with the resulting `user` object.

Make sure to follow through [async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I made a few changes to my code, but this is what i needed

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code

`async` keyword must be in the front of the return type.

```
 public static async Task<UserClass> GetUserInfo()
    {
         Task<UserClass> ui;
         ui = GetUserData();
         HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
         return ui;
   }
```

and then use

```
var user = await UserClass.GetUserInfo();
if (user.ReadOnly)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: @cFrozenDeath why downwote?

Answer (score 1):

You should await your call to UserClass.GetUserInfo();

```
var user = await UserClass.GetUserInfo();
if (user.ReadOnly){
      ////code to execute
}
```

and the method signature should be :

```
public async static Task<CurrentUserData> GetUserInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this shouldn't even be *compiling* unless the method with the `await` operator is also `async`:

```
public static async Task<CurrentUserData> GetUserInfo()
```

Once that's the case, you simply await the method like any other `async` method:

```
var user = await UserClass.GetUserInfo();
```

Which itself would be in an `async` method:

```
public static async Task<CurrentUserData> GetUserInfo()
```

and so on all the way to the top of the stack.